# Access Database Without phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, phpmyadmin, hostname

I have the hostname, username, and password for a MySQL Database. But I do not have access to the location of phpMyAdmin. How can I download the database w/o use of PHPmyadmin?

Comment: You must make an effort to clarify your question!

Comment: If you don't have access, how would you be able to download it..?

Comment: I have the **hostname** the **username** and the **password** to a MySQL Database. But I do not have the phpmyadmin. My credentials will work, but I need a way to download the database.

Comment: There's always the command line...

Comment: Write a script and run a recursive query and generate the data? If you don't have PMA access you're kinda out of luck as far as I know.

Comment: @PRPGFerret I wouldn't be opposed to running a script, but I don't know what to type, or where to use it.

Comment: hostname wouldn't happen to be localhost?

Answer (score 1):

I use MysqlWorkbench-- I love how user friendly it is and it gives me the opportunity not only to connect to DB, but during new development create EER diagrams. I use its tools to create new EER's and then, auto-deploy them and update EER's and Database Schema via the tool directly to the server. You can also download database, backup, and generate EER from the Database Schema.